# AVAssetImageGenerator - Getting error code -11800

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avasset, avassetimagegenerator

I've tried doing this synchronously:

```
AVURLAsset *as = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *ima = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:as];
NSError *err = NULL;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(0, 30);
CGImageRef imgRef = [ima copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
UIImage *currentImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef];

callback(currentImg, err);
```

And asynchronously:

```
AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;

CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);

AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef imgRef, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error){
    if (result != AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        NSLog(@"couldn't generate thumbnail, error:%@", error);
        callback(nil, error);
    }

    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];
    callback(thumbnail, nil);
};

CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(128, 128);
generator.maximumSize = maxSize;
[generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:thumbTime]] completionHandler:handler];
```

Either way I get `AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800` - `NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred` and a nil image.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

EDIT

Here's a third option I just tried but with the same resulting errors:

```
    NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey : @NO };
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:options];
NSArray *keys     = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"readable"];
[asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^() {

    AVAssetImageGenerator *generate = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];

    NSError *err = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 30);

    CGImageRef imgRef = [generate copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        callback(thumbnail, err);
    });
}];
```

Comment: Have you checked the `AVAsset` after you instantiate it? If the URL is not pointing at a local resource, it may not have loaded its tracks yet.

Comment: @ChrisH For the third option I tried I tried using both `readable` and `playable` as keys for `loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys` -- shouldn't at least using `playable` ensure that the asset is loaded before running the block?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the -11800 error code Unknown error is hard.

When you get this error code there is often in one of the logs like the system log an OSStatus code value associated with your application. The OSStatus code will provide a useful guide as to what is going wrong.

However finding out what the OSStatus code means can be difficult. I now go to the SDK I'm building against and search the frameworks folder using:

```
find . -name "*.h" -exec grep -H "statuscode" {} \;
```

where statuscode is the numeric value found.

Tracking down this extra bit of info is worth the time as it does help to determine the cause of the problem.